# Why Can't I access MySQL on EC2

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

I'm currently trying to access a MySQL DB hosted with apache on an EC2 isntance with the code below. I've opened up 3306 on my EC2 security group, but I can't connect. Anybody have any ideas? Thanks

```
   // Database host
   $host = 'myIP'; 
   // Database name
   $db = 'myDBName'; 
   // MySQL username
   $uid = 'root';
   // MySQL password
   $pwd = 'myPassword';
```

Comment: I'm assuming this is not the problem, but the code you posted doesn't have any lines that would actually connect to a database.  Also, does your db config allow root to connect remotely?

Comment: @robert the first part of your comment is, as you said, obviously no the issue. The issue was, however, that my root was configured only to allow local host. I created a separate user with % permissions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a private key to access you db . get the private key , use puttyAgent for running it . and then you will have a secure session to your server.